# Vector's push_back implementation using memcpy

Tags: c++

Given the following push_back code:

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(const T& item) {

if (_size == _capacity) {
    _capacity = _capacity + (_capacity > 1 ? (_capacity / 2) : 1);
    T* newVec = new T[_capacity];
    memcpy(newVec, _ptr, _size*(sizeof(T)));
    delete [] _ptr;
    _ptr = newVec;
}
_ptr[_size++] = item;
}
```

While the vector's class contain these members:

```
T*  _ptr;
size_t _size;
size_t _capacity;
```

Is that implementation safe..? Will memcpy do his job correctly even if T is polymorphic type?

Would love to hear some suggestions about how to improve the implementation.

Comment: If `T` has a copy constructor, `memcpy` won't invoke it, and you have a problem.

Comment: Note that a vector can only hold objects of the same type. It's not able to hold elements of different polymorphic types, so there's no need to worry about working correctly for polymorphic types.

Comment: Aside from what you're asking about, `std::vector` doesn't use `new T[]` to allocate the memory. Firstly because it takes an `Alloc` template parameter or `std::allocator` by default, to make it more flexible. Secondly because `new T[]` would call the `T` default constructor on each element, which the vector is not permitted to do because the `vector` interface doesn't require that the element type `T` must be default-constructible in order to use `push_back`. Given that `std::vector` has had a lot of work put into it, you could probably improve your `Vector` by following this design ;-)

Comment: So, you say I should use malloc instead?

Comment: @Rouki: no, I say you should use `std::allocator<T>` or an `Alloc` template parameter instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Don't use `std::memcpy`

You may only use `std::memcpy` on trivially copyable objects. Otherwise it's undefined behaviour.

You can, however, just copy all elements by hand. [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is suitable, as it may be specialized for trivial types:

> In practice, implementations of `std::copy` avoid multiple assignments and use bulk copy functions such as `std::memcpy` if the value type is TriviallyCopyable

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(const T& item) {
  if (_size == _capacity) {
      size_t new_cap = _capacity > 0 ? 2 * _capacity : 2;    
      T * newVec = new T[new_cap];
      std::copy(_ptr, _ptr + _size, newVec);
      std::swap(_capacity, new_cap);
      std::swap(_ptr, newVec);
      delete[] newVec;
  }
  _ptr[_size++] = item;
}
```

Note that your original implementation divided the capacity if the vector was too small.

## More improvements

If you use `std::allocator` (or a compatible class), things get a little bit easier. You would use [`.allocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) to get memory, [`.construct(pointer, value)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) to actually *construct* objects, [`.destroy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/destroy) to call their destructors and [`.deallocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate) to remove memory previously created with `.allocate`. Thus you don't need a default constructible object if you just want to use `.push_back()`.

The following code is a quick minimal sketch. Note that there are some problems, for example `reserve()` isn't exception safe, as the allocated memory in `tmp` needs to be cleaned up if a constructor throws.

```
template <typename T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
class Vector{
public:
  typedef typename Allocator::pointer pointer;
  typedef typename Allocator::size_type size_type;

  Vector() : _ptr(0), _capacity(0), _size(0){}
  ~Vector() {
    if(_capacity == 0)
      return;
    while(_size > 0)
      pop_back();
    _alloc.deallocate(_ptr, _capacity);
  }

  void reserve(size_type new_cap){
    if(new_cap <= _capacity)
      return;

    // allocate memory
    T * tmp = _alloc.allocate(new_cap);

    // construct objects
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; ++i){
      _alloc.construct(tmp + i, _ptr[i]); // or std::move(_ptr[i])
    }

    // finished construction, save to delete old values
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; ++i){
      _alloc.destroy(_ptr + i);
    }

    // deallocate old memory
    _alloc.deallocate(_ptr, _capacity);
    _ptr = tmp;
    _capacity = new_cap;
  }

  void push_back(const T& val){
    if(_size == _capacity)
      reserve(_capacity > 0 ? 2 * _capacity : 1);    
    _alloc.construct(_ptr + _size, val);
    _size++; // since T::T(..) might throw
  }

  void pop_back(){
    _alloc.destroy(_ptr + _size - 1);
    _size--;    
  }

  T& operator[](size_type index){
    return _ptr[index];
  }

private:
  pointer _ptr;
  size_type _capacity;
  size_type _size;
  Allocator _alloc;
};
```

Comment: What if it is not a trivially copyable object? what should I do in that case?

Comment: @Rouki [`std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable), but even then your implementation (the OPs one) is not correct as you are overwriting already default-constructed values without calling the destructor.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Err, `new[]` calls `T::T()`. `_ptr[0..._size)` contains the original elements, `_ptr[_size..._capacity)` default constructed, so there's no "confusion". However, this version of `.push_back` needs `T` to be default constructible, which could indeed be averted by using placement `new`.

Comment: @Zeta,  you're right.  I've deleted my comment.  I was thinking of `malloc`!

Answer (score 3):

This is not safe, for example if `T` is doing this:

```
struct T
{
    T* myself;
    T() : myself(this) {}
    void foo() { myself->bar(); }
    void bar() { ... }
};
```

Since you moved the memory location of the object by simply moving it's memory without calling constructors/destructors, `myself` will not be updated and when you call `foo` afterward, it will call `bar` with an invalid `this` pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. got it. Any good solution to improve safety?

Comment: @Rouki You could use `std::move(_ptr, _ptr+_size,newVec)` which should be safe, although not efficient. For efficiency, you'd allocate raw memory and move-construct in place, then default-construct the new elements only.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine what would happen if `T` was itself a `vector`.

Now you have two vectors pointing to the same buffer, and they will *both* delete the buffer... bad idea.

(Well, technically it's undefined behavior the moment you `memcpy`. I just gave you the most likely result.)

Comment: Why? he didn't show his copy-constructor and we can assume it implemented well. Why you think `T` and current vector are pointing to a same buffer? -- He's implemention `push_back` not a copy or assignment method.

Comment: @MM.: the `memcpy()` copies an array of type T elements to a new block of memory (using a raw memory copy, not one of T's constructors). As an example, at that moment `newVec[0]._ptr` and `_ptr[0]._ptr` will be pointing to the same memory block for their own elements.  When `delete[] _ptr` is executed, `newVec[0]._ptr` will hold a stale pointer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Thinking more, yes you're right. I thought he is not talking about memcpy's issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe in general - but C++11 provides [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) :

```
#include <type_traits>
...
if (std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value)
    // *can* use memcpy...
```

Comment: And what if it is NOT trivially copyable?

Comment: @Rouki - then you CAN'T use memcpy.

Comment: Fastest replacement for the memcpy then?

Comment: @Rouki - the problem is, you're invoking the default constructor on each element in the array, and then looking to copy. You might look at [placement new/delete](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html) and allocation with `::operator new (size_t)`.